# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'theme' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is null

Tags: reactjs, next.js, styled-components, react-context

I'm working on a Next.js application with TypeScript and I have this error:

"TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'theme' of '(0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext)(...)' as it is null."

This is my _app.tsx file:

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"

import ContextProvider from "../context/Context"
import { Context } from "../context/Context"

import GlobalStyle from "../styles/global"

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { theme } = useContext(Context)

  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </ContextProvider>
  )
}
```

This is my Context.tsx file:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react"

import Light from "../styles/themes/Light"
import Dark from "../styles/themes/Dark"

interface Props {
  theme: any;
  setTheme: any;
  handleTheme(): void;
}

export const Context = createContext<Props>(null)

export default function ContextProvider({ children }) {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(Dark)

  function handleTheme() {
    setTheme(theme.title === "Dark" ? Light : Dark)
  }

  return(
    <Context.Provider 
    value={{
      theme,
      setTheme,
      handleTheme
    }}
    >
      {children}
    </Context.Provider>
  )
}
```

I've been getting this error and I'm not sure how to solve it.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The line where you use 'createContext' in your ContextProvider component needs to have an initial object based on your interface 'Props' and not null.

Comment: I'm starting to study Next.js alone, hence the difficulty. Okay, changes made. Now in .app.js I get the following error in the theme variable: Property 'theme' does not exist on type '{}'.

Comment: @WellingtonAlmeida You passed it an empty object, you need to pass it an object that has the properties from your interface (theme, setTheme, handleTheme)

Answer (score 0):

In Nextjs 13 you need to put the "use client" directive in the top of your component.